# Interplay of statistical factors (PCA) and market factors (value, momentum, low vol, ...)

Tags: pca, factor-loading, factor-investing

Is there any research done on the interplay between statistical factors (as a result of principle component analysis PCA) and the market factors (especially value, size, low vol, momentum, quality)?

I think that if I can represent a factor by a portfolio then I can look at the exposures of this portfolio to the factor. This is more or less easy for momentum and other ranking constructions. I have to check how to deal with the changing nature of the PCAs. They change through time and so do the market factors. I will see.

The question: who has done analysis on this? Are there posts or papers on the net?